# How to get value of a variable when variable has been sending through layout handle in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, email-templates, variables

Layout handle in **email_template.phtml**

```
{{layout handle="email_product_list" order=$order product=$product check=$check area="frontend"}}
```

I need to know how can i get the value of `$check` variable in `phtml` file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't test yet but that is same as magento1. try to get it by.

```
$this->getCheck();
```

or

```
$block->getCheck();
```

Comment: ok let me check @Quaisar.

Comment: King__Satti , good job.....

Comment: @BabyinMagento thanks for appreciating my work. you words mean lot to me

Comment: Sorry @QaisarSatti

Comment: @QaisarSatti, I am getting NULL when iuse $this->getCheck(); in my phtml file. Please help.

Comment: @MeetaliGupta can you share your code?